# Output content in PHP witout echo

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to output something like `<h3>Something</h3>` in PHP without using echo? Say I had one class file for displaying information from a database, but I wanted it to be pure PHP and no large echo statements in there. Could I do this or do I need to use echo

thanks

Comment: Yes, use a [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) system/framework.

Comment: "but I wanted it to be pure PHP" - echo is pure PHP. You can go the OO way and have classes that have methods that, in turn, use echo. If you mean you don't want whole HTML files in echo, you can `include` an HTML or PHP file that has the markup outside the PHP scope in it; Or if you really wanna get technical, you can use `print` too, but that's not what's gonna make a difference, really

Answer (score 1):

Try closing and re-opening PHP tag some that:

```
# PHP CODE
?>
<h3>Something</h3>
<?php
#MORE PHP CODE
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways, `print()` - `die()` - `exit()`, HTML, `heredoc` and `nowdoc`:

```
<?php

print("<h3>Something</h3>");
```

and

```
<?php

die("<h3>Something</h3>");
```

and

```
<?php

exit("<h3>Something</h3>");
```

and good 'ol HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<head></head>

<body>
<?php
// some code
?>

<h3>Something</h3>
<?php
// some other code
?>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**Edit:** Plus, as `sudo.ie` states in an answer, using [**heredoc**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

There is also [**nowdoc**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) which lets you do stuff like, and taken from example #6:

```
<?php
$str = <<<'EOD'
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using nowdoc syntax.
EOD;

/* More complex example, with variables. */
class foo
{
    public $foo;
    public $bar;

    function foo()
    {
        $this->foo = 'Foo';
        $this->bar = array('Bar1', 'Bar2', 'Bar3');
    }
}

$foo = new foo();
$name = 'MyName';

echo <<<'EOT'
My name is "$name". I am printing some $foo->foo.
Now, I am printing some {$foo->bar[1]}.
This should not print a capital 'A': \x41
EOT;
?>
```

- Which may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe what you are looking for, using a [**heredoc**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
<?= <<<EOT
<h1>
    This is some PHP text.
    It is completely free
    I can use "double quotes"
    and 'single quotes',
    plus $variables too, which will
    be properly converted to their values,
    you can even type EOT, as long as it
    is not alone on a line, like this:
</h1>
EOT;

?>
```